# How to move all images with javascript queryselectorall in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I can move one image by define for each but I need to do it in for loop, I have a code as I show below,

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".yikama");
var el;
for (i = 0; i = elem.length; i++)
{
    var el = elem[i]
    el.addEventListener("mousedown", start)
    function start() {
        addEventListener("mousemove", move)
    }

    function move(b) {
        b = b || event;
        el.style.left = b.pageX - 290 + "px";
        el.style.top = b.pageY - 190 + "px";
    }
    el.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
    })   
}
```

But I had an error which is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at 1:141
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: It should be `for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)`

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work

Comment: In `for` loop second statement should be condition like `i < elem.length`. But you have it as assignment `i = elem.length`.

Comment: Thank you, Karan, but it did not work

Comment: @AlpayToprak What exactly do you wish to do? Move all the images when the mouse pointer hovers over any one of them? Or maybe move them individually?

Comment: your `start()` function need `el` to `addEventListener`, just like `el.addEventListener("mousemove", move)`.

Comment: I want to move each of them individually, images coming from SQL database as many as possible so I need a for loop

Comment: Thank you linchong,  It fixed the error but again I could not move images

Comment: When you drag the picture, will the move event be triggered?

Comment: Yes, it should be triggered, and then I need to drop it somewhere I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple mistakes as first you need condition in for loop's second statement like `i == elem.length` or `i === elem.length`. From your code you should be using `i < elem.length`. **P.S.** You are having an assignment `(i = elem.length)` here which will not work. It will assign `elem.length` to variable `i` and based on value it will return `true` or `false`. In your case it will never break the loop and go for infinite loop.

Second mistake is you are not assigning `move` event to any element. You need to use `el.addEventListener` & `el.removeEventListener` inside `start` & `mouseup` event.

Use `let el` instead of `var el`, so it won't cause [closure issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Add `b.preventDefault();` inside `move` function.

Try complete code like below.

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".yikama");
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
    let el = elem[i]
    el.addEventListener("mousedown", start)
    function start() {
        el.addEventListener("mousemove", move)
    }

    function move(b) {
        b.preventDefault();
        b = b || event;
        el.style.left = b.pageX - 290 + "px";
        el.style.top = b.pageY - 190 + "px";
    }
    el.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        el.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
    })   
}
```

Comment: Now I can move it which one I want but I could not finish moving and set position for the image, I need to move always. What can I do for this situation

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move image by `style.left` and `style.top`, you need to `set a position` to image

You also need to add `preventDefault` in the mousemove event, otherwise the mouseup event cannot be triggered after the mousemove event.

The reason is that the browser is also dragging and dropping its own native image, you need to use preventDefault to prevent the default event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .yikama{
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <img class="yikama"
        src="/xx/xx" alt="" />
</body>
<script>
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll(".yikama");
    var el;
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        var el = elem[i]
        el.addEventListener("mousedown", start)
        function start() {
            el.addEventListener("mousemove", move)
        }

        function move(b) {
            b.preventDefault()
            b = b;
            el.style.left = b.pageX - 290 + "px";
            el.style.top = b.pageY - 190 + "px";
        }
        el.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
            el.removeEventListener("mousemove", move)
        })
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to move my pictures step by step, for example first I want to move the first picture and then I want to move next to one, is this code okay for this situation, because I can only move the first image. should I use if clause for each image

Comment: Unfourtanetly, it did not work, I could not move each my images, and I could not drop image where I want to